# How can I check if a Flex 4 component belogs to a stategroup from actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, states

I have a component with various states. From mxml, the includeIn and exclueFrom properties takes state groups as an argument. How can I check if the current state belongs to a state group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`State` has property `stateGroups` that is `Array of String`:

```
var n:int = states.length;
for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var state:State = states[i];
    if (state.name == currentState)
    {
        trace("Current state (" + currentState + ") state groups: " + state.stateGroups);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't realize that states are more than strings. I'd expect the currentState to be of object 'State' or an easier way to get the currentState Object and groups array. So now I have a StatesUtil with some static methods.